# Regex expression to avoid '' records in a RDD after splitting the text

Tags: regex, pyspark, rdd

I am new to PySpark RDD and Regex, and I tried a simple example to read a text file and then split the text using every non-alphabetic character as delimiter:

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("essay.txt")
rdd2 = rdd.flatMap(lambda x: re.split('\W+', x))
```

The result is nearly what I wanted, except that there are `''` records when the original text contains more than one consecutive non-alphabetic characters. (Edit: I found that the `''` may occur because of the line break)

For example, I have these lines in the essay.txt file:

```
data = [(1001, 'Introduction to Programming', 9, 50),
        (1002, 'Introduction to Algorithms', 9, 50),
        (1003, 'Introduction to Data Structures', 9, 40),
        (2002, 'Operating Systems', 12, 40),
        (2051, 'Advanced Data Structures', 6, 40),
        (3048, 'Networking and Cloud Computing', 12, 60)]
```

I got these results in rdd2:

```
['data', '1001', 'Introduction', 'to', 'Programming', '9', '50', '', '', '1002', 'Introduction', 'to', 'Algorithms', '9', '50', '', '', '1003', 'Introduction', 'to', 'Data', 'Structures', '9', '40', '', '', '2002', 'Operating', 'Systems', '12', '40', '', '', '2051', 'Advanced', 'Data', 'Structures', '6', '40', '', '', '3048', 'Networking', 'and', 'Cloud', 'Computing', '12', '60', '']
```

I believe there are two choices: I may remove the `''` records from `rdd2`, but I'd prefer changing the Regex expression so consecutive non-alphabetic characters are treated as one. Is the latter possible?

Comment: Then use `re.findall(r'\w+', x)`

Comment: can you provide an example of a record that has those consecutive non-alphabetic characters and what is the result you get? because in theory '\W+' does match consecutive characters already, as the '+' should match one or more, and by default those modifiers are "greedy" which means they take as many chars as they can

Comment: Put the sample data in the question, not a comment.

Comment: This problem seems to be specific to using RDD. If you just read the file as a text string, the only `''` in the result is at the very end (because `)]` is a delimiter)`.

Comment: Try `list(rdd.flatMap(str))` to see what's actually being passed to the lambda. I suspect there are some empty strings.